# how to get children elements of an html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a var saved in my JS custom object (code below is from inside the class):

```
var toolbar;

this.create_toolbar = function() {
    self.toolbar = document.createElement('div');
    $(self.toolbar)
        .html('<ul>' +
            '<li id="insert_bold"></li>' +
            '<li id="insert_em"></li>' +
            '<li id="insert_hyperlink"></li>' +
            '<li id="insert_code"></li>' +
            '<li id="insert_image"></li>' +
            '</ul>')
        .insertBefore(self.editTextarea); // just a textarea on the page
}
```

The toolbar gets created and placed successfully, and self.toolbar now holds the object for the new div. However, when trying to bind the <li>'s to clicks I can't seem to get anything to happen:

```
$(self.toolbar).children("li#insert_bold").click(function() {
    alert("just checking");
});
```

To be clear, after the above, nothing is happening when I click <li id="insert_bold">

Is there something that I am missing? I am fairly new to jQuery....am I allow to put a variable that holds an [object object] in the $()? If not, how should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) here, like this:

```
$(self.toolbar).find("li#insert_bold").click(function() {
  alert("just checking");
});
```

[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) only looks at *immediate* children, `<li>` is beneath the `<ul>` though, so it's not an immediate child.

---

Be aware though if you intend on having multiple instances of this on a page (I'm guessing this is likely the case), you should use classes instead (IDs need to be unique), then use a class selector, for example: `$(self.toolbar).find("li.insert_bold")`.

Comment: couldn't you just use the `#insert_bold` selector?

Comment: @hunter - you could certainly, though this is more restrictive so it's not identical.  The point was more to show why `.children()` wasn't getting the correct element.

Comment: good point on the classes. you are right, initially this was to be only once a page, so i've been going through and making everything more flexi. thanks!

Comment: @Nick Not quite sure, but I think $('li#id',self.toolbar).click() is  better (optimization), you avoid using find()

Comment: @Omar - it's actually the opposite, that gets transformed into a `.find()`, and takes extra logic to get there, so it's slower :)

Answer (score 1):

While Nick has solved your question, I don't think this is a good idea, especially if you have a large number of HTML elements binding.

When I have a rather small number, I do gather the items in an object inside the main constructor function

```
this.el = {
$button : $('.button','#div'),
$submit : $('.submit','#div')
};
```

Then when I need an element, I just call it with (this), assuming you are using prototype functions.

```
this.el.$button.click(function () {

});
```

If you many elements to deal with, 20 or more, I'll recommend that you opt for a JavaScript FrameWork. [Backbone Js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone) is a good one.